# Why should we used a square bracket when using a calculated property for an object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I saw in some lecture the following code:

```
   const weekdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
const openingHours = {
  [weekdays[3]]: {
    open: 12,
    close: 22,
  },
  [weekdays[4]]: {
    open: 11,
    close: 23,
  },
  [weekdays[5]]: {
    open: 0, // Open 24 hours
    close: 24,
  },
};
```

I can't understand why we need to wrap **weekdays[i]** with a square brackets?
Can someone explain me?

Comment: Because if you don't, the syntax will be invalid, since dynamic property names require `[]`s around them

Comment: You don't need too, you could just remove weekdays array.  Not sure why to use a const array for keys here, seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @Keith, it is an example from a course i am watching

Comment: Try running  it without the `[]` and see the error thrown

Comment: @charlietfl i got: ',' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, and also ' sign is required?

Comment: By the way, it is closed with an example that is **so not relevant** to my question

Comment: The only place `'` is being used is for the string delimiters for `weekdays` array, so yeah, I guess it's required there?

Comment: Does a dynamic property inside [] brackets must be from a string type?